# Executing PowerShell script from C# wpf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, powershell

I have a PowerShell script, that executes a SQL file(that holds commands for exporting data from an XML file into SQL Server Database table) in PowerShell script:

```
Function Export-Data
{
    $srvrInst = $env:COMPUTERNAME;
    $db = "DataModel.PAModel";
    $apc = "C:\DCT\SQL\AccountingPeriodCases.sql";
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $apc -ServerInstance $srvrInst -Database $db;
}
Export-Data;
```

I have a requirement of calling this Smpl.ps1 file from WPF-C# code. 
That is, when the checkbox corresponding to the data export is checked, then this Smpl.ps1 should be called and executed.

So I have the C# code snippet:

```
 int DataBox_Execute()
        {
            Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
            rs.Open();

            int k = 0;

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            if (DataBox.IsChecked ?? true)
            {
                ps.Runspace = rs;
                ps.AddScript(@"C:\DCT\LogCapture\Smpl.ps1").Invoke();
                k = 1;
            }
            rs.Close();
            return k;
        }
```

But I don't understand why it is not getting executed. When i go back and check in SQL server database, the table which was supposed to be having data, is till empty.

I'm sure the script is working fine, because when I try executing script via PowerShell only, then the SQL database table appears full with the exported values from the xml file as i wanted it to work.

so i wanted to knw if there was anything that wrong with the program part in WPF-C#.
Could anyone please help guys?

Comment: [AddScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) expects you to pass the actual content of the script, not just the path to the file on disk.

Comment: so is there any alternative for passing the scriptfile? @boxdog

Comment: You could try reading the script in using `Get-Content` and pass that instead.

Comment: @boxdog: According to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx AddScript does expect the path to the script.

Comment: @PalleDue, I'm not convinced the documentation is accurate.  For example, I just realised the page I originally linked to has examples of using `AddScript` that don't actually use that method!  One thing I'm 100% sure of is that passing a snippet of executable code does work, as I've used that technique lots of times.  It _may_ accept either a path or a snippet, but it seems quite poor that it doesn't allow the user to explicitly say which they used (e.g. using an `IsScriptPath` flag or similar), hence leaving the method to 'guess' by parsing the input.

Comment: @PalleDue AddScript works for other path i had tried in C#... i Guess there is a clash when im using Invoke-SqlCmd as all other normal ps1 files are getting executed fine in c#...

Comment: @PalleDue  i figured out what was going wrong...
The problem was as mentioned in: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx
by you..

ps.AddScript(@"C:\DCT\LogCapture\Smpl.ps1").Invoke();

was to be given a boolean value:
ps.AddScript(@"C:\DCT\LogCapture\Smpl.ps1",true).Invoke();

now this works Perfect...

thank you for help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Read comments and check:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx

Check if you have included a Boolean value for the AddScript path.